# Is my Saga structure the correct solution? (NServiceBus)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nservicebus, saga

I'll cut straight to it. I'm trying to automate credit card payments via a file sent to our bank. Card payments are not validated with the bank in real time. The bank processes payments overnight and sends out a response file the following day with both successful and unsuccessful payments.

I've a web app that when it accepts or cancels a payment, a message containing the details of the payment/cancel is sent (via Bus.Send) to a command message processor.

The processor then publishes (via Bus.Publish) this for all services to see.

One service needs to do the following:

- start a saga with the receipt of the first message
- issue a timeout request for the close of business
- track all subsequent messages as they come in (in saga)
- upon receipt of timeout, turn payment and cancellation messages into bank file.

The problem is I don't know how to store collections of messages (or anything else for that matter) in a saga as List<>'s aren't allowed as virtual members.

Here's the current saga structure:

```
public class PaymentRequestCancelledSagaBase : IContainSagaData
    {
        // the following properties are mandatory
        public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Originator { get; set; }
        public virtual string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }

        // List of all the received PaymentRequestedMessages
        public virtual List<PaymentRequested> PaymentRequestedMessages;

        // List of all the received PaymentCancelledMessages
        public virtual List<PaymentCancelled> PaymentCancelledMessages;
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: IList<T> is supported, see the Manufacturing sample. I would keep the list of payment ids in that list

Comment: So the Bank file processor would use those payment IDs to look up the transaction amounts rather than transport those around in the message? In that case, I'll need to add a data access layer to processor to fetch the data if not in the messages.

Comment: You could store that info as well, pretty much like the OrderLine (DTO) is used in the Manufacturing sample.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure if my thinking is in line with Udi et al, but I've always understood saga data to be very lightweight *metadata* about the messages, it shouldn't contain much actual message data.

You *could* have a saga for each payment request and corresponding approval/cancellation, but let's assume that the bank either requires you to batch them all together per business day or charges you a fixed amount per file, which is common...

In that case, underlying the messaging system (NServiceBus) you likely do or *should* have some sort of transactional system which is actually *tracking* the *transactions themselves*. If they're being grouped into some type of batch (i.e. a business day) then the batch must have an ID. *That* is what the saga should be referencing, in addition to basic information about the state of the entire process (i.e. did you get the response from the bank yet?).

A service bus isn't a system in and of itself, it's a way for independent systems and components to communicate with each other. Sagas are actually intended to be deleted once they're finished (via `MarkAsComplete`) so they're really not the place to store "permanent" information.

In my world the saga data would look something like this instead:

```
public class PaymentProcessingSagaData : IContainSagaData
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Originator { get; set; }
    public virtual string OriginalMessageId { get; set; }

    public virtual int RequestBatchId { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? WhenRequestBatchClosed { get; set; }
    public virtual string BankRequestFileName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? WhenRequestFileSent { get; set; }
    public virtual string BankResponseFileName { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? WhenResponseFileReceived { get; set; }
    public virtual int PaymentBatchId { get; set; }
}
```

That corresponds to an order of operations like:

1. Request sent to app, which creates/appends to batch and posts a `PaymentRequested` event.
2. Subscriber picks up `PaymentRequested` event, and if necessary creates a new saga and sets `RequestBatchId`, which becomes the saga correlation ID. Then it sets the timeout for close of business.
3. Timeout handler closes the batch, sets `WhenRequestBatchClosed`, and publishes a `PaymentRequestBatchClosed` event.
4. Subscriber picks up `PaymentRequestBatchClosed` event, creates the payment file (sets `BankRequestFileName`), publishes a `RequestFileAvailable` event saying that the file is ready.
5. Subscriber picks up `RequestFileAvailable` event and initiates upload process which (for example) FTPs the file to the bank server, updates `WhenRequestFileSent`, and publishes a `RequestFileSent` event.
6. Monitoring process (or another timeout handler) detects response file, updates `BankResponseFileName` and `WhenResponseFileReceived` and publishes a `ResponseFileAvailable` event.
7. Subscriber picks up `ResponseFileAvailable` event, processes the file, creates the payment batch, updates the `PaymentBatchId`, and optionally posts a final `PaymentsProcessed` event and completes the saga.

Of course you don't necessarily need these `When` DateTime fields, you could just as easily have boolean flags indicating which steps are complete.  But the important thing is that **your saga is keeping track of the transaction *state*, not the transaction *data*.**

Don't make the mistake of trying to jam everything into a saga. It's not meant to take the place of a transactional system, it's just a bit of glue to hold it all together.

Comment: The web application has no knowledge of how many payments may or may not have been added and doesn't generate a batch. The batch generation wasn't going to happen until the timeout message is received and the messages are collated. A unique identifier generated by the processor would be, in effect, the batch ID. This is included in the bank file and in the BankFileSent message which is sent once the file is sent. Another Processor consumes the BankFileSent and updates the payment records. When the response comes back, we have the unique identifier and the payment IDs for the final update.

Comment: @Fellmeister: I'm afraid you're going down the wrong avenue. A saga is not a replacement for a transactional system or database, it's an extension to one. You're welcome to try to carry on without one, but my very strong recommendation - and I think what many others will also recommend - is that you track transactional data (payment requests) within a permanent application-specific OLTP database, not attempt to do this within the scope of a saga. It wouldn't take more than a few hours to get a SQLExpress or Firebird database going with NH or EF, and will eliminate a lot of future headaches.

Comment: So in the case where the saga handles a batch by its ID, when the file is ready to be compiled, should the FileCreator app then query the live DB to get the transaction details to put in the file based on the PaymentID?

Comment: I've gone over my design and revised it taking into consideration your saga design and the purpose it serves. Thank you for taking the time to explain these points to me, it's been a long road and I've still a fair way to go.

Comment: @Fellmeister: That is what I would do, yes. Glad to hear you're making progress.

Comment: How do you test to see if there is a saga currently running? Can you find a saga without mapping it to a specific ID in the message? Should you not make this kind of assumption?

Comment: @Fellmeister: I think you should ask that as a separate question. But the short answer is that sagas don't really "run", they just *exist*, there's nothing actually *happening* with them unless a correlated message is being processed. Furthermore it probably wouldn't be a good idea to try model a "current saga" or "ambient saga" because in a production environment there would very likely be more than one - for example, what if you add a new bank, or a new bank account? If you have a specific use case in mind then best elaborate in a new question.